# mysql query improvement with join issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema on Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2d785/4/0

The result table is also listed there.

If we observed the result. for mtg_ID 3. The skpr_id are duplicated for each topic_id and the same from attendee table each entry is duplicate.

EXP_ID   MTG_ID  SPKR_ID     TOPIC_ID    EXPENSE

```
1   1   1   1   100
**2     2   2   2   100
3   2   3   2   200**
4   3   4   4   100
5   3   2   4   200
6   3   5   4   100
7   3   6   4   100
8   3   7   4   100
9   3   8   4   100
```

I want the following result

```
EXP_ID  MTG_ID  SPKR_ID     TOPIC_ID    EXPENSE
1   1   1   1   100
2   2   2   **2**   100
3   2   3   **3**   200
4   3   4   4   100
5   3   2   4   200
6   3   5   4   100
7   3   6   4   100
8   3   7   4   100
9   3   8   4   100
```

I am missing few joints. Applying group by is not resolving the issue.
I want to get resut within same query without derived table. Could any one help me ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: Please the the added result set in question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you simply want to group by your exp_id.

Going off the query from your fiddle I added the last line and got the output you were looking for.

```
SELECT 
    ex.exp_id,
    m.id as mtg_id,
    ex.spkr_id,
    xsm.topic_id,
    ex.expense
FROM
    expense ex
INNER JOIN meeting m ON (ex.mtg_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN mtg_spkr xsm on (m.id = xsm.mtg_id  )
GROUP BY ex.exp_id
```

and got this

```
| EXP_ID | MTG_ID | SPKR_ID | TOPIC_ID | EXPENSE |
|--------|--------|---------|----------|---------|
|      1 |      1 |       1 |        1 |     100 |
|      2 |      2 |       2 |        2 |     100 |
|      3 |      2 |       3 |        2 |     200 |
|      4 |      3 |       4 |        4 |     100 |
|      5 |      3 |       2 |        4 |     200 |
|      6 |      3 |       5 |        4 |     100 |
|      7 |      3 |       6 |        4 |     100 |
|      8 |      3 |       7 |        4 |     100 |
|      9 |      3 |       8 |        4 |     100 |
```

Comment: group by loses data of topic_id because sometimes, one meeting has 2 spkr_ids and each spkr_id has different topics. See the updated insert data in fiddle with group by. Now the row 2 and 3 has same topic_id 2. However, I want topic_id 2 in row 2 and topic_id 3 in row 3. This is what I am unable to resolve.